# I can't vote on an answer issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

So, I cast a vote on an answer, and then almost right away, I cancelled that vote by hitting the arrow again, since I realized I didn't understand the answer. At this point neither arrow is highlighted.

After careful consideration of the answer, I decide it should be up voted. When I tried to up vote the answer, I got the message that my vote is locked in unless the answer is edited because I voted on it XX minutes ago.... yet I have no vote cast on that answer currently! And I cannot now cast a vote either way.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent vote gaming, you can only change your vote within the 5 minute original interval, and only a limited number of times.

If you want to change your vote, you must edit the post, or have someone else edit it.