# White popup containing "undefined"

Tags: bug, status-completed, popups

I have got a white, semi-transparent banner sliding down from the top (like in the chat) and containing the word "Undefined" several times today on SO proper, every time immediately after re-starting a system and opening the browser for the first time.

When I change pages, it disappears and doesn't come back again. I didn't manage to take a screenshot.

Chrome <strike>4</strike> (correction: 5) on Windows 7

Comment: Seconded, Chrome 5 on Gentoo. I've been waiting until I could get a screenshot and/or determine why it happens, but I haven't managed either yet; it's been happening for a few days

Comment: I *think* it's the box alerting you that you've been automatically logged in, and it only happens if you click a link while the page is still loading, before that box appears

Comment: Also Opera 10.61 on Windows Vista. Same behavior you describe. @Michael: I'm not clicking anything, just letting the page load.

Comment: It works on the main stackexchange.com site, but gives me the white box on every other site I've tried.

Comment: Repro on Opera 10.61 on OSX. Every site that I've tried, except for stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9):

I saw this popup today on all Stack Exchange sites (using Opera 10.61 on Windows XP). Here's a screenshot (click to enlarge):

[image: Note the freehand arrow!]

The *Close This Window* link executes the code `javascript:closeGAuthNotification()`.

**Update:** Looks like this popup is an automatic login notification, at least this is what it says today after I cleared the browser cache. So, the problem with "undefined" was probably due to the cache.

Just FYI here're the steps to see the popup::

- Clear the browser cache, cookies and persistent storage.
- Restart the browser.
- Open [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).
- Log in using Google OpenID.
- Sign in to Google.
- After you return to SO, open another SE site, e.g. [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). *Note that you're not logged in here yet.*

After ~5 seconds, a popup appears saying that you've been automatically logged in and suggesting to refresh the page:

[image: More freehand arrows]

Comment: That's exactly the one I meant.

Comment: @Pekka, Helen: How is this response an answer? Come to think of it, how is the original post a question?

Comment: @Pekka You should probably wait and accept the answer that fixes the problem, not the one that proves it exists :)

Comment: @Peter You realize you're on meta? The original post is a bug report; this post is to include a picture demonstrating the bug

Comment: @Michael I'm pretty sure this is a bug on SO's side, so I presume somebody will just stamp this `status-something` one day, no need to mark that accepted :)

Comment: @Michael - I realize I'm on Meta. The giant button in the upper right of the screen reads "Ask Question" ---- I guess the implied question is, "Could someone fix this?"

Comment: @Peter Yes? I checked your profile assuming you're new, but you're not; bug reports have always been this way. You did [the same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61429/i-cant-vote-on-an-answer-issue) last week

Comment: @Michael - Please allow me to needlessly nitpick in peace.

Comment: @Peter ahahahaha! But you *are* needlessly nitpicking. This is a perfectly valid Meta question/bug report - and answer/visual confirmation. :)

Comment: @Peter: Like @Michael said, this is just a screenshot to illustrate the problem. I would have added it to @Pekka's post if I had enough rep to edit.

Comment: Gentlemen please calm down. :)

Comment: @Pekka: @Michael is right; please hold back the accept mark for an official response from Jeff or other team members.

Comment: @Helen done, although it doesn't really matter: There are a lot of bug reports that will never get any official response except for a `status-something` tag; also, open bugs are tracked through the `status-something` tag rather than their accept status. Meta is different :)

Comment: Same browser, same problem. Windows Vista here though. It displays the message I assume it is supposed to - "welcome back, you have been logged in" in IE.

Comment: @Helen: When you say ALL stackexchange sites, are you including http://stackexchange.com? That is the only one that works for me.

Comment: Repro'd on Opera 10.61 on Windows 7 x64. Seen on both SO.com and meta.SO.com

Comment: @Larry: Didn't try stackexchange.com yesterday. But today the popup displays "welcome back" instead of "undefined" on all sites, including the main se.com site.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I'm having trouble replicating this.</strike>

Do me a favor and clear your cache, then close the browser and try again.

---

This has been resolved.  If you should experience it *again* clear your javascript cache and, if it persists, ping me.

Comment: @Kevin me too :) It seems totally arbitrary, but happened mostly when  I totally restarted the machine (no idea why). I'll restart the small machine (without clearing the cache first, then with) and see whether it occurs again

Comment: @Kevin restarted without clearing the cache, didn't turn up. I'll keep an eye on it, clear the cache and post if it comes up again.

Comment: @Pekka - there's a check once per session, and it'll only appear if you're not already logged in (barring some minor edge cases that should be fixed tonight).

Comment: @Kevin check the update by @Larry above - maybe it gives you more info

Comment: @Pekka - still makes me think bad javascript in the cache.

Comment: @Kevin: I've tried clearing the cache. Doesn't fix it. Are you unable to reproduce the bug?

Comment: @Kevin: After clearing the cache, the popup now says "Welcome back, you've been logged in" (see my updated post).

Comment: @Larry - a-haha, I've found the Opera bug.  Will fix post haste, though it won't be on production till tonight (PST) sometime.  Thanks for your assistance.